# Parentheses matching algorithm java

Tags: java, algorithm

This is my implementation of the parenthesis matching algorithm. However can someone tell me what is wrong. I get true all the time for example for input: {}(

```
public static boolean checkString(char [] stringToCheck){

    Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<Character>();

    for(int i= 0; i<stack.size();i++){
        char current = stringToCheck[i];
        if(current == '(' || current == '{' || current == '['){
            stack.push(current);
        }
        if(current == ')' || current == '}' ||current == ']'){
            if(stack.isEmpty()){
                return false;
            }
            char top = stack.peek();
            if((current == ']' && top == '[') ||(current == '}' && top == '{')  ||                      (current == ')' && top == '(')){
                 stack.pop();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(stack.isEmpty){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're running the loop on stack, wich is empty, so, no iteration is executed at all. Just change the for condition to analize stringToCheck length instead of stack size.

Comment: still have problem for input [] it returns false

Comment: I can't tell from reading the code, but does this method handle mismatched brackets; as an example ([)]?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `stack`'s size as bound instead of `stringToCheck`'s. The stack is initialized just before so your loop is just skipped.

Answer (score 0):

your program is correct except at mentioned comments in below code

```
public static boolean checkString(char [] stringToCheck){

        Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<Character>();
        int n = stringToCheck.length; // take the length of the given char array
        for(int i= 0; i < n;i++){
            char current = stringToCheck[i];
            if(current == '(' || current == '{' || current == '['){
                stack.push(current);
            }
            if(current == ')' || current == '}' ||current == ']'){
                if(stack.isEmpty()){
                    return false;
                }
                char top = stack.peek();
                if((current == ']' && top == '[') ||(current == '}' && top == '{')  ||                      (current == ')' && top == '(')){
                    stack.pop();
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(stack.isEmpty()){ // function call of stack isEmpty()
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use stringToCheck length for the loop instead stack size. Then, `stack.isEmpty` isEmpty is a method and you forgot the parenthesis.

```
public static boolean checkString(char [] stringToCheck){

    Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<Character>();

    for(int i= 0; i<stringToCheck.length();i++){
        char current = stringToCheck[i];
        if(current == '(' || current == '{' || current == '['){
            stack.push(current);
        }
        if(current == ')' || current == '}' ||current == ']'){
            if(stack.isEmpty()){
                return false;
            }
            char top = stack.peek();
            if((current == ']' && top == '[') ||(current == '}' && top == '{')  || (current == ')' && top == '(')) {
                 stack.pop();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(stack.isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```